# issues bootstrap 3 Carousel changing height to 0px and marigin to -.....px

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

The Carousel I added to my site behaves really strange. In a periode of 2 the slide slides up. The height of the parent div changes to 0px and the margin of the child div gets a negative margin. In a the examples on the bootstrap site this isn't happening. I copied the latest code from the bootstrap site, can't find what i am doing wrong.

I would love it if someone could help me.

http://humandemo.cloudaccess.host Header right at the top op the page.

Code used:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>   
        <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="/images/page-specific/home/iPhone-Comp-hw.png" alt="Second Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="/images/page-specific/home/iPhone-Comp-hw.png" alt="First Slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the work of the [mootools-more.js](http://humandemo.cloudaccess.host/media/system/js/mootools-more.js). This script includes [the `Fx.Slide` class](http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.6.0/Fx/Fx.Slide):

> The slide effect slides an Element in horizontally or vertically. The contents will fold inside.

Try to comment this script.

Comment: I did some research and indeed mootools conflicts with bootstrap. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/475 The fix is if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') { 
(function($) { 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.carousel').each(function(index, element) {
$(this)[index].slide = null;
});
});
})(jQuery);
}

Answer (score 0):

@Jeroen: I have checked your website and tried some changes with Css by "Inspect Element" and As per me You should check div id="myCarousel" and div class="carousel-inner". If they have been set with some height or not. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Bootsrap carousel code is perfect, there is no issue with that. There may be issue with your another script, I have used your code in the codepen and its works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research after the answer of @Gleb Kemarsky, thank you for that. And indeed mootools conflicts with bootstrap, see: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/475

The fix is:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') { 
(function($) { 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.carousel').each(function(index, element) {
$(this)[index].slide = null;
});
});
})(jQuery);
}
```